# How to burn-in a home built pc running centOS?

Tags: linux, computer-building, home-server, stress-test

I have built my first PC from components yesterday I have installed CentOS 6.5 on it as this will be my ZFS home based server.

How do I burn-in a home built PC on linux? Is there some live CD ISO that can throughly test all the hardware before I start relying on the PC.

Answer (score 1):

Stress Linux has a bootable ISO that should work for what you need.

http://www.stresslinux.org/sl/